# Difference between // and round() in Python

Tags: python, rounding, division

Is there a difference between using `//` (Integer Division) and the built-in `round()` function in Python? If I understand correctly, both will round to the nearest Integer but I'm unsure if the behaviour of both the function and the operator is exactly the same at all times. Can someone clarify? Can both of them be used "interchangeably"?

Comment: Um... division and rounding are two completely different things...

Comment: Huh? // and round **are** division and round.

Answer (score 2):

`//` is *floor* division, `round` rounds to *nearest*. `//` stays integer at all times, `round` using `/` converts to `float` before rounding back, which might not work at all for large enough `int`s, and can lose precision for smaller (but still large) `int`s.

If you need floor division of `int`s, *always* use `//` (you can do ceiling division too, with `-(-num // div)`). It's always correct, where `round` (and `math.floor`) might not be (for `int`s exceeding about 53 bits). `round` is more configurable (you can round off to a specified number of decimal places, including negative decimal places to round off to the left of the decimal point), but you want to avoid converting to `float` at all whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
>>> round(5 / 2)
2
>>> round(5 / 2, 1)
2.5
>>>
```

The `round` function gives you more control over the precision of rounding. The `//` operator provides the floor (rounds down) of dividing the two.

Consider also:

```
>>> round(20 / 3)
7
>>> 20 // 3
6
>>>
```

Comment: hmm why does round(20/3) and 20//3 give different results?

Comment: so basically, // rounds down and round() rounds up?

Comment: `//` rounds down to the nearest integer. `round` rounds to the _nearest_ number. And gives you the option of specifying decimal places of precision.

Comment: `20 / 3` is 6.666....7, and the _nearest_ integer is `7`.

Answer (score 0):

`//` and `round()` are two different things.
`//` is divide, then floor
`round()` is a function to make a float number shorter.

```
>>> 10 // 3   # 10 divide to 3, then floor
3
>>> round(10 / 3, 2)   # 10 divide to 3, take 2 number after the dot
3.33
```